# Authorize attribute on entire project in .net mvc for security

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization, authorize-attribute

I am applying authorize attibutes on each classes.

So is it possible to avoid this, and secure my entire web application at once?

Something like at "Namespace" level?

I am using .net core mvc application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the above worked. But I got the solution. So following worked for me.

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                             .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                             .Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
```

Comment: My solution works if you implement your own `YourCustomAuthorizationAttribute` which implements `AuthorizeAttribute`

Answer (score 2):

You should add your `Authorization` filter in `ConfigureServices` method on startup.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(typeof(YourCustomAuthorizationAttribute));
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey, Buddy. I hadnot applied this solution till date. But now I tried this. Before my edit, it was giving compile error, after edit, it is giving error as => **System.ArgumentException: 'The type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute' must derive from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IFilterMetadata'.'
**

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be late. But ideally, the check must happen only if there is an authorization header found. It is never possible for all pages in a project to require authentication... There must be at least one login page that does not need authentication

Comment: Guess what, we have whole external project just for login. So another entire project needs authentication...!!!